# How to make check mark's color different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have refered [prettyCheckable](http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable). and tried to implement it. But didn't get success. I want to implement checkbox same like it. Anyone help me with this.
I used [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/VYUQt/light/) and apply following code.

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" class="prettyCheckable" value="1" id="Test1" name="Test1" data-label="Right positioned label (no param)" />
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" class="prettyCheckable" value="2" id="Test2" name="Test2" data-label='data-labelPosition="left"' data-labelPosition="left" />
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">
<br/>
<div class="input-wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" class="prettyCheckable" value="1" id="color1" checked name="color1" data-label="Default (no-param)" />
</div>
<div class="input-wrapper">
<input type="checkbox" class="prettyCheckable" value="1" id="color2" checked name="color2" data-label='data-color="green"' data-color="green" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is working for me in Chrome.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Lowkase I am using chrome.

Comment: Not sure what to say.  The jsfiddle you linked works properly in that the checkboxe and radio button appearances have been altered by prettyCheckable.  What result are you getting other than "didn't get success"?  Screenshot maybe?

Comment: jsfiddle works fine in Opera & FireFox on Mac

Comment: @Lowkase I am getting error,.find() in not a function. Though I am using latest jquery.

Answer (score 1):

could it be a mixup with doctypes??

- you are doing `/>` => html4 doctype
- `checked` => html5 doctype

Which doctype do you use?

Then you could check if jQuery was loaded before you load the prettyCheckable script?

Comment: It is html5. I am using the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS link of the page you are referring to
http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/js/prettyCheckable/prettyCheckable.css

You can check the code there.